# Include method calls from original thread when Runnable started by Handler throws exception

Tags: java, android, exception, handler, stack-trace

I'm calling `post()` method:

```
void post() {
    new Handler().post(() -> {
        throw new RuntimeException("Something went wrong...");
    });
}
```

And I'm getting the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Something went wrong...
                  at com.package.MyApp.lambda$post$0(MyApp.java:39)
                  at com.package.MyApp$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Is it possible to include the callers of method `post()` in the stack trace?

In other words, let's say I'm calling `foo()`, which calls `bar()`, which finally calls `post()`:

```
void foo() { bar(); }
void bar() { post(); }
```

What I'm going to achieve is to get a stack trace with the information about `foo`, `bar` and `post`.

Comment: from where I see it, you want to throw this exception when ever you encounter a crash which you must have surrounded with a try() catch block, you can pass that stack trace using exception.printStackTrace()  to your post method and then print it.

Comment: Isn't it already included in the stack trace?

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki Information about `post()` is included, but what I'm looking for is information about: who called `post()`. I'll edit my question because I've described the problem not precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` to know the elements of stack trace of your current thread.